# Why does Format round numbers differently from CInt?

Tags: .net, vb.net

These expressions return different results:

`CInt(36.5).ToString` ' returns "36"

`Format(36.5, "0")`   ' **returns "37"**

`CInt(35.5).ToString` ' returns "36"

`Format(35.5, "0")`   ' returns "36"

Is the rounding method used by these functions different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked is clearly "yes" because, if it was "no", they would not produce different results. As per the documentation, `CInt` rounds a fractional part of 0.5 to the nearest even integer. Based on your results, `Format` clearly rounds up. This is presumably because the behaviour of `CInt`, known as bankers rounding, is intended to prevent problems when summing multiple rounded values but that's obviously not going to be an issue when using `Format`, which produces a `String` rather than a number.

By the way, don't use `Format` in the first place. It's a VB6 holdover. Use `String.Format` for composite formatting or just `ToString` for simple formatting. They may behave the same way as `Format` but you shouldn't really be using relics like that anyway. It is implemented specifically to behave as it did in VB6, which might be the reason for that seemingly inconsistent behaviour.

EDIT:

This is yet another example of why you should ALWAYS read the documentation. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions#behavior), which applies to `CInt`, specifically states that banker's rounding is used:

> If the fractional part is exactly 0.5, the integer conversion functions round it to the nearest even integer. For example, 0.5 rounds to 0, and 1.5 and 2.5 both round to 2. This is sometimes called banker's rounding, and its purpose is to compensate for a bias that could accumulate when adding many such numbers together.

This also applies to standard .NET methods like `Int32.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32`. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#Specifier0), which applies to `Format`, specifically states that rounding away from zero is used:

> The "00" specifier causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used. For example, formatting 34.5 with "00" would result in the value 35.

This also applies to standard .NET methods like `String.Format` and `Double.ToString`, as well as string interpolation. As the first documentation states, the purpose of banker's rounding is to prevent issues when adding many rounded numbers but that is not an issue when you're converting a single number to a `String`, hence the more commonly used rounding away from zero is applied. If you understand what's happening then you can make sure to write code that behaves the way you want and the documentation exists to help you understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

`CInt` and all integer conversion functions will round a fraction to the nearest even integer.

From [Type Conversion Functions - Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions):

> Fractional Parts. When you convert a nonintegral value to an integral type, the integer conversion functions (CByte, CInt, CLng, CSByte, CShort, CUInt, CULng, and CUShort) remove the fractional part and **round the value to the closest integer**.
>
> If the fractional part is exactly 0.5, the integer conversion functions round it to the nearest even integer. For example, 0.5 rounds to 0, and 1.5 and 2.5 both round to 2. This is sometimes called banker's rounding, and its purpose is to compensate for a bias that could accumulate when adding many such numbers together.

`Format` rounds to the specified number of digits, to the nearest. This is different from the integer conversion functions mentioned above

From [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#rounding-and-fixed-point-format-strings):

> For fixed-point format strings (that is, format strings that do not contain scientific notation format characters), numbers are rounded to as many decimal places as there are digit placeholders to the right of the decimal point. If the format string does not contain a decimal point, **the number is rounded to the nearest integer**. If the number has more digits than there are digit placeholders to the left of the decimal point, the extra digits are copied to the result string immediately before the first digit placeholder.

If you need better control over how your number is rounded, see the [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0), Floor, Ceiling